# Rails 7 Razorpay integration , always need to refresh page

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-7, razorpay

So I integrated Razorpay into my Rails 7 App and everything is working fine, it takes the payment and payment is success, everything works absolutely fine BUT whenever i redirect to the page where i have to click the button to start payment, that page always needs to be refreshed first, then after one refresh, the button starts working and it takes the payment, I have seen that i need to use `document.addEventListener("turbo:load", funcName)` where `funcName` is a function which has all the code to make button work, but still after doing this, i still need to refresh the page to make the payment button work.

***when it is redirected to payment page for the first time, this is shown in the console***
[image]

***when the page is refreshed once, the console shows no errors***
[image]

***this is the code for button***

```
<button id="rzp-button1"> Pay with Card / UPI / Netbanking </button>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/checkout.js"></script>
    
    <script>
       var options = {
          "key": "<%= Rails.application.credentials.dig(:razorpay, :public_key) %>",

          "amount": "<%= "#{@RazorOrder.amount}" %>", 

          "currency": "INR",

          "name": "Sapna Xerox",

          "description": "Payment to Sapna Xerox for Order#<%= "#{@order.id}" %> ",

          "order_id": "<%= "#{@RazorOrder.id}" %>"
    
           "handler": function (response){
        
             window.location.href = "http://localhost:3000/orders/<%= "#{@order.id}" 
             %>/successpayment/?rz_odr_id=<%= "#{@RazorOrder.id}" %>"
        
                                       
            },
    
            "prefill": {
              "name": "<%= "#{@order.name}" %>",
              "email": "<%= "#{@order.user.email}" %>",
              "contact": "<%= "#{@order.user.phone_number}" %>"
             },
             "notes": {
                    "address": "PDA Engineering College Road, Gulbarga - 585102."
              },
              "theme": {
                          "color": "#00aeae"
               }
               };
    
               var rzp1 = new Razorpay(options);
               rzp1.on('payment.failed', function (response){
                                        alert(response.error.code);
                                        alert(response.error.description);
                                        alert(response.error.source);
                                        alert(response.error.step);
                                        alert(response.error.reason);
                                        alert(response.error.metadata.order_id);
                                        alert(response.error.metadata.payment_id);
                                });
               document.getElementById('rzp-button1').onclick = function(e){
                                    rzp1.open();
                                    e.preventDefault();
                                }
    </script>
```

Anyone knows how to fix this?? :')